# javascript object into new array object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Can you help me with a JSON transformation?

Given structure:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "606f990042cc89060c54a632",
    "number": 1293,
    "date": "2021-04-08",
    "__v": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": "606e478042cc89060c54a631",
    "number": 997,
    "date": "2021-04-07",
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Transformed structure:

```
[
  {
    "id": "weight",
    "data": [
      {
        "x": "2021-04-08",
        "y": 1293
      },
      {
        "x": "2021-04-07",
        "y": 997
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I solve that most efficiently? Should I use lodash-library or built-in functions of JavaScript?

Can you give me a hint?

Comment: See [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (with [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)).

```js
let arr = [{"_id":"606f990042cc89060c54a632","number":1293,"date":"2021-04-08","__v":0},{"_id":"606e478042cc89060c54a631","number":997,"date":"2021-04-07","__v":0},{"_id":"606d3508c7f841e27c8a25a1","number":1068,"date":"2021-04-06"},{"_id":"606d3508c7f841e27c8a25a0","number":890,"date":"2021-04-05"},];
let res = arr.map(({date:x,number:y})=>({x,y}));
console.log(res);
```